# how can i submit a redux-form form from material-ui's dialog actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

in my code im using a Dialog component from 'material-ui/Dialog'

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import {reduxForm, Field} from 'redux-form';

class NewTaskDialog extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Dialog
                title="New Task"
                modal={false}
                actions={[<FlatButton type="submit" label="Ok" primary={true} onTouchTap={this.props.onRequestClose} />]}
                open={this.props.open}
                onRequestClose={this.props.onRequestClose}
            >
            <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
                <Field component="input" name="name" />
            </form>
            </Dialog>
        );
    }
}

NewTaskDialog = reduxForm({
    form: 'NewTaskForm'
})(NewTaskDialog);

export default NewTaskDialog;
```

so since the Dialog accepts `actions` prop, how can the button inside of actions be used as a submit trigger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

- Use [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to reference the `<form />` and then call `submit()` on the reference whenever the dialog button is clicked
- Define hidden button under `<form />` and manually trigger `onClick` there via [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)
- Use [remote submit](http://redux-form.com/6.6.0/examples/remoteSubmit/)

---

I'd go with the first approach because of its simplicity.

Comment: thanks, i tried the first solution and it works perfectly

Comment: I am getting / page not found. Can you point to an illustration?

Comment: Is there any way you could add an example ?

Comment: honestly, I stopped using redux-form, no offence to the author or anything - but I do think it is overengineered, difficult to work with, has plenty of bugs and doesn't help much. I stopped using material-ui as well, because of performance issues, sorry. I'd say skip redux-form and if you're good with CSS skip that too.

Comment: @Lyubomir You stopped using them ... so what do you use instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML5 `<button>` attribute `"form"`:

```
<form id="my-id">
  <input />
</form>
<button type="submit" form="my-id">Submit</button>
```

[HTML Button tag doc on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: Unfortuantely, this solution won't work because the Button component is outside the form

Comment: <button> attribute "form" designed specifically for that case, so it would work

Comment: This does indeed work, and it's by far the simplest solution if you don't mind adding an ID to your form.

I've got a MUI dialog with a Redux form inside the content, and a submit button outside the form. I gave my <form> an ID and added form="<my form ID>" to my submit button and it worked fine.